# Why did Captain America have a secret identity in the 1980s comics?

Tags: marvel, comics, captain-america

In a 1986 issue of Captain America, I discovered that not only was Captain America working as an artist for an ad agency, but he was doing so as Steve Rogers, with no one knowing that he was also Captain America.

[image]
*From Captain America #309*

It was always my understanding that the general public knew Steve Rogers was Captain America. His identity is currently listed as public on his [Marvel Wiki page](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Steven_Rogers_(Earth-616)). Why was he using a secret identity in the mid-80s? Was his identity really not publicly known until recently?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Captain America's identity wasn't always public. After 9/11 Marvel decided that real heroes don't keep their identities private and went around revealing publicly the identities of Captain America, Iron Man, Spider-Man, etc.  Captain America ended up revealing his identity on television cameras, when he was calling out terrorists early in the 2002 Captain America (volume 4?) run.

Later on in that 1980's run Steve Rogers becomes a freelance artist for Marvel Comics drawing his own comic book.

Comment: I'm not sure how far this goes to answering the question. Plenty of information on his latest public identity outing, but none on his former?

Comment: Steve Rogers becomes an artist for Marvel...? Sounds more like something Deadpool would do.

Comment: In the Golden Age, during WW II, nobody knew who Captain America was under the mask.  Classified information.  After he went MIA, and after the war, eventually the identity was available, as shown in "Captain America" #155 (1972).  But that story didn't make clear if the information was easily available at the public library or required special permission to see the government files.  Anyhow, his identity was not wide, public knowledge.  But also, the name "Steve Rogers" is pretty generic..  A websearch brings up five people with that name right away. Not a name for the boss to be excited over

Answer (score 5):

The answer is that his identity was secret until 2002. There was no "previous outing."

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is an old thread, but I came across this while doing research and I know other people will, so I thought I'd write in and provide clearer answers (no offense to previous posters, but your answers aren't very well researched).

Steve Roger's identity had been kept a secret since his inception circa Captain America Comics #1. When not on a mission as Cap, he distanced his civilian identity from his alter ego by acting like a bumbling accident-prone private in the military. It was a similar dynamic to Superman when he was Clark Kent back in the day.

People who knew during the war were Bucky, and top military brass such as General Chester Phillips. Nazi spy Cynthia Glass also knew (Adventures of Captain America #1), as did President Franklin Roosevelt (Captain America #255). The core members of the Invaders (Sub-Mariner, Human Torch, and Toro) also found out at some point, but there aren't any specific issues where Steve implicitly reveals his identity to them.

In the 1950s, William Burnside (who became the 1950s Captain America) figured out Steve Rogers’ true identity. He shared this with Jack Monroe who was his Bucky. This was detailed in Captain America #155.

After he was revived in Avengers #4, the Avengers present discovered his identity (Thor, Iron Man, Giant-Man, and the Wasp).

In Cap's solo exploits (which started up again in Tales of Suspense #59) Cap began interacting with Agent 13 (in issue #75 of that series). He fell in love with her and at one point publicly retired in Tales of Suspense #95 so that he could be with Agent 13. That didn't pan out and when Cap got his own solo series, he was a target of Hydra who was attacking him both in and out of costume, so he faked his death (Captain America #111-114). This involved leaving behind a life-like mask making everyone believe Steve Rogers was a false identity. If that sounds kind of flimsy to you, they revisited that moment in Avengers #71 and explained that the Space Phantom used some advanced technology to wipe out everyone's memory of Cap's true identity.

Over the years, they kind of played it fast and loose as to which of the Avengers knew Cap's true identity. SHIELD (Nick Fury and Sharon Carter specifically) always seemed to know. Although there was never any huge "reveal" story, the first two teams of Avengers (Thor, Iron Man, Wasp, Hank Pym, Hawkeye, Scarlet Witch, and Quicksilver) all learned his identity early on and he kept them in the know. The same could be said about the more trustworthy Avengers, like the Vision. The roster from the 90s seemed to be in the know as well (Black Knight, Sersi, Crystal, Hercules, and the like) but there are no specific issues where he is shown implicitly revealing his identity to them. The Falcon has always been in the know since pretty much his first appearance in Captain America #118.

He told his old childhood friend Arnie Roth (Captain America #270), his girlfriend Bernie figured it out on her own (Captain America #275), the Red Skull learned when he transferred his mind into a clone of Steve Rogers body (Captain America #350), and he revealed his identity to Diamondback when they started dating (Captain America #371). His relationship with Connie Ferrari ended when she learned the truth in Captain America (vol. 3) #44.

This is by no means an exhaustive list, but that's more or less everyone of note.

Cap finally re-revealed his identity to the public in Captain America (vol. 4) #3, because he had just killed a Middle Eastern terrorist named Faysal Al-Tariq. He unmasked to take ownership of the death and to hopefully deter other terrorists from striking at America in retaliation. He figured that if they knew who he was under the mask they'd target him directly. He has maintained a public identity ever since, time of this writing.

That said, a lot of people are also incorrect about what Captain America represents and why his identity was kept secret.

His identity was kept secret because it was a military secret — especially after the creator of the Super Soldier Serum was murdered by a Nazi assassin. Other than high-ranking military officials, only those with a need to know had access to the truth. Per Captain America Annual 2001 even sitting Presidents after Roosevelt did not know his true identity. That information was sealed in a file that could only be opened in the event that Captain America was confirmed to be dead.

When SHIELD was created, the director of the agency was also allowed to know the truth. But Nick Fury might have also found out the truth during the war, they are never clear on that.

His need to keep his identity a secret wasn't because of any of this "he represents the American people" non-sense other posters are saying. Once he was no longer working directly for the government and/or military it became a matter of protecting those he knew in his personal life. Same as anyone else.

Also, the assertion that Captain America represents the American people is incorrect. Yes, Captain America became disillusioned between Captain America #175-183. That taught him that he can't always support the government of the day, as governments (like people) are fallible. They can do things wrong. They can be led astray.

Captain America represents the *American Dream.* Something that transcends the government of the day and the sensibilities of the general public. He represents life, liberty, freedom, the pursuit of happiness, and that all people are created equal. That's what he represents and that's what he fights for.

Comment: your answer is good as it is, but it could be better if you could shorten it up a bit, or if thats not possible - highlight the main points of your answer so as to help other users and the op in viewing the answer

Answer (score 2):

Part of The Answer is that the Captain America identity/character, along with the uniform, name and shield were the invention and property of the United States Government, which is why there was a Red Scare era Captain America and Bucky running around in the 1950s while Steve Rogers was on ice and MIA.

By the Watergate Era, Marvel did a famous epic storyline in the Captain America book called Secret Empire, wherein the unmasked (but unseen) mastermind of the criminal conspiracy is heavily implied to be the sitting President, Richard M. Nixon. The shock of this revelation led to a brief identity crisis for Steve Rogers, wherein he briefly renounced the Captain America identity and became a wandering Knight Errant under the name Nomad — since then? The Marvel orthodoxy has always been that while Captain America is the Champion of The American Nation ( and it’s Legitimate Government), Steve Rogers is, and Always will be The Champion of The American PEOPLE.

This all came to a head during the Iran Contra era, when Steve’s conscience compelled him to resign his Army commission (he is an actual Captain in the US Army), turn in his uniform and shield and renounce the Captain America identity rather than carry out legal orders from the White House to carry out Covert Actions in support of Small wars in Central America, and thus, a new solider was promoted to serve as Captain America for a time, whilst Steve himself continued to fight crime and serve with the Avengers in a new black and red costume, calling himself The Captain.

It’s like Bruce Wayne explains in The Dark Knight Rises — Captain America is an Idea, and the idea is that ANYBODY could be Captain America under the mask.