# Did Captain America actually illustrate his own comics at some point?

Tags: marvel, comics, captain-america

<sub>***Part of my [long](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125557/is-civilization-v-run-by-aliens)-[running](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105489/is-it-true-that-suzanne-collins-was-forced-to-add-a-love-triangle-to-the-hunger) [series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/134614/51226) of calling out TV Tropes.***</sub>

The TV Tropes page [Recursive Canon](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RecursiveCanon) says this:

> At various times, Captain America has been the artist for the in-universe Captain America comics. No, really.

Is this true? Has the 616 universe version of Steve Rogers ever been shown illustrating his own, or anyone else's comics?

Comment: Your series complements mine of calling out Wikipedia ([here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131384/was-the-technodrome-actually-based-on-the-death-star) and [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133597/was-captain-picard-named-after-the-piccard-twins)).

Comment: @Praxis [I'm all for calling out Wikipedia.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/132764/51226)

Comment: Skeptics are an endangered resource in a world that desperately needs them. And I mean real skeptics - people who ask the questions because they're interested in the truth, not people who ask the questions because they want to prove their enemy wrong. It's the most valuable thing sites like StackExchange bring to the world.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, in [Captain America #311](http://www.captainamericalibrary.com/superhero-library/captain-america/captain-america-comic-details.aspx?id=CA1&issue=311&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), Steve Rogers quits working as an advertising exec (his [secret identity](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15823/why-did-captain-america-have-a-secret-identity-in-the-1980s-comics?rq=1)) and goes to work for Marvel. They put him to work illustrating Captain America comics.

[image]

Comment: If you had told me there was a property that was further up its own back end than Leisure Suit Larry 3 this morning, I wouldn't have believed you.

Comment: The very panels I was about to Google for. +1

Comment: So did Steve Rogers draw this page?

Comment: No.  At this time Steve Rogers was temporarily illustrating the in-universe Captain Rogers magazine.

Comment: And this issue of the in-universe magazine has him illustrating Captain America #311.  It's the kinda thing that gives the Watcher a headache.

Comment: This is very meta.

Comment: Wait, Captain America had a secret identity?

Comment: @DCShannon - [Yup](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15823/why-did-captain-america-have-a-secret-identity-in-the-1980s-comics?rq=1). And a pretty lame one at that.

Comment: Could someone tell me why this question was downvoted? I fail to understand a reason for it.

Comment: @KyloRen - Because someone is going around downvoting my answers and probably decided to downvote the question too, to try to seem even-handed.

Comment: Whoops I meant to also say the answer, it is a great answer that I had absolutely no clue Steve Rogers did this. There has to be something for serial downvoting correct?

Comment: @KyloRen - The serial downvoting algorithm detects multiple downvotes at the same time. This is rather more subtle, one or two downvotes per day. Death by a thousand cuts.

Comment: A moderator needs to do something, it skews the results and is bad for the forum.

Comment: @KyloRen - I've mentioned it to a moderator. Nothing's happened. Next on my list is reporting it to a CM so that they can send me their incredibly patronising "*downvotes are a normal part of SE life*" pro-forma email.

Comment: Ahh well, I suppose there is nothing more you can do. It is wrong though.