# Are there any differences in deaths between the comic series (The Infinity Gauntlet) and the film (Avengers: Infinity War)

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, adaptation-comparison, avengers-infinity-war, the-infinity-gauntlet

Both in the comic book series *The Infinity Gauntlet* and its film adaptation *Avengers: Infinity Wars* does Thanos

> kill half the population of the universe.

**Are there any differences in deaths between the two events?**

I'm primarily interested in named characters that exist and are seen or referenced in both the comics and the films. I'm not interested in any other deaths than Thanos' finger snap.

Comment: One big difference: In comics, snap kicks half of population of the universe out of existence **instantly** without any *disintegration effect* and *dust*.. Also, everyone dies simultaneously.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm primarily interested in named characters that exist and are seen or referenced in both the [**comics**](https://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Infinity-Gauntlet-1991/Issue-1?id=44283) and the films.

There are significant differences in the comic and movie. The *snap* is the instigating factor in the comic run and the snap happens almost at the end of Issue #1 when Thanos *already* has the fully-loaded gauntlet. There's no fight to stop him as such, just to undo the snap (*Avengers 4?*).

Fortunately, Cap has a recap of missing heroes (so far) in Issue #2 of *The Infinity Gauntlet*.
[image]

Other than that:

| Hero | Comics | Films |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Vision** | ok | destroyed |
| **Scarlet Witch** | not snapped | snapped |
| **Spider-man** | not snapped | snapped |
| **Black Panther** | snapped | snapped |
| **Drax** | not snapped | snapped |
| **Dr. Strange** | not snapped | snapped |
| **Hawkeye** | snapped | not snapped |
| **Nick Fury** | not snapped | snapped |
| **Nebula** | not snapped | not snapped |

*These relate to **snapped** deaths etc at the start of the the comic Infinity War. That's not to say that the "currently OK" heroes don't perish *during* the comic IW.*

Comment: This is where Cap’s [day job as an illustrator](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135313/did-captain-america-actually-illustrate-his-own-comics-at-some-point/135315#135315) really came in handy! “The entire universe is in peril! I must assemble the remaining Avengers *and* put together a mood board!”

Comment: I think Hawkeye can be updated based on the Endgame trailer.